# Android adding multiple views to viewgroup

Tags: java, android, viewgroup

I have a simple question. I have an arrayList of views I want to add to a ViewGroup. I currently am iterating through them with a for loop and adding them individually.

```
ViewGroup commentList = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.comment_list);
for (View commment: comments) {
    commentList.addView(commment);
}
```

Can I do this all at once with a single call? Like an addAll() method? I feel like this would be more efficient, especially if I have a lot of views I'm adding....

Comment: What is occuring behind the scenes is most likely the same... Speed will not increase by a method such as `addAll()` but it could clean up your code...

Comment: yeah i think so you do it but it won't affect your complexity it will remain same

Comment: I'd say you want to use a `ListView` + `Adapter` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating through the views if there are a lot is fairly efficient. If this ViewGroup is going to always have a lot of views you may want to consider using a view type that uses an adapter and recycling / reuse otherwise you'll have a lot of views that are in memory yet are off screen.